# bulkWrite - TypeError: Cannot create property '$set' on number '0' at applyTimestampsToUpdate - mongoose or mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, bulkupdate

I tried have **bulkWrite** query for update multiple and different documents in a single time, customer order multiple products at the time updating the product quantity details. I found [bulkWrite updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#updateone-and-updatemany) query. this bulk array updates at a single time.

### Code :

while upding the **key value** `update: { $set: { 'colorName' : null} }` working fine. but using nested array key value `update: { $set: { 'sizes.$.qty' : data.qty} }` not working.

```
poductModel.bulkWrite(arrayValue.map((data) => ({
            updateOne: {
          filter: { _id: data.productQtyDetailsId, 'sizes.name' : data.sizeName },

          update: { $set: { 'sizes.$.qty' : data.qty} } 
      //working fine
      //update: { $set: { 'colorName' : null} } 

        }
      }))).then(err,result => {

      })
```

### JSON data:

```
    [
  {
    "qty": 8,
    "productId": "5d31567ea23d120f087a9aaf",
    "productQtyDetailsId": "5d316373b356873504e78be7",
    "sizeName": "4",
    "colorName": "green",
  },
  {
    "qty": 5,
    "productId": "5d31567ea23d120f087a9aaf",
    "productQtyDetailsId": "5d31567ea23d120f087a9ab1",
    "sizeName": "4",
    "colorName": "blue",
  }
]
```

### Mongo DB data :

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d316373b356873504e78be7"),
    "colorName" : "green",
    "productId" : ObjectId("5d31567ea23d120f087a9aaf"),
    "sizes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "4",
            "qty" : 5.0,
            "price" : 1500.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "5",
            "qty" : 6.0,
            "price" : 1600.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "6",
            "qty" : 7.0,
            "price" : 1700.0
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d31567ea23d120f087a9ab1"),
    "colorName" : "blue",
    "productId" : ObjectId("5d31567ea23d120f087a9aaf"),
    "sizes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "4",
            "qty" : 5.0,
            "price" : 1500.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "5",
            "qty" : 6.0,
            "price" : 1600.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "6",
            "qty" : 7.0,
            "price" : 1700.0
        }
    ]
},
...
]
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Apart from the way you are using `then()` **its not supposed to be that way** and assuming `arrayValue` is the JSON data you posted the `bulkWrite` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying to update a field not present in model schema.

The issue can be solved by using `<model>.collection.bulkWrite` or by adding the field to schema (at least both these actions did work in my case).

Comment: I had the same issue today!

Thank you so much for your answer. It worked perfectly!!!